# Problems with iAds and iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, ios8, iad

When I run my app on iOS 7, all iAds works like a charm in every view controllers. But when i run my app on iOS 8 and navigate around the app when i return to main view or maybe in other view before charged, the iAds shows blank. I've tried all types of code, and with all of them have the problem.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
if (!_adBanner) {
    _adBanner = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height, 320, 50)];
    [_adBanner setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:_adBanner];
}

_adBanner.delegate = self;}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewDidDisappear:animated];
_adBanner.delegate=nil;
}
```

//delegates

```
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{
if (!_bannerIsVisible /*&& _original*/) {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[_adBanner setAlpha:1];
banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -banner.frame.size.height);
[UIView commitAnimations];
    _bannerIsVisible = YES;
}
}
-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
if (_bannerIsVisible) {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[_adBanner setAlpha:0];
banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height);
[UIView commitAnimations];
_bannerIsVisible = NO;
}
NSLog(@"%@",error);
}
```

And in console get this error: "Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=7 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad was unloaded from this banner" UserInfo=0x7a698c20 {ADInternalErrorCode=7, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad was unloaded from this banner}"

Comment: Try removing _adBanner.delegate=nil; from viewDidDisappear and put _adBanner init code in viewDidLoad!

Comment: I have the same problem with it.

Comment: Console error have other information?

Comment: You can check if _adBanner.superview != nil and in Header file i wetted ADBannerViewDelegate?

Comment: Yeah, in header file i have ADBannerViewDelegate. I dont know why on iOS 8 is not working well.

Comment: And adBanner.superview != nil.

Answer (score 0):

I am having exactly the same issue and I want to post an answer here which doesn't solve it in my case (so please accept that THIS IS NOT AN ACTUAL answer) but I wanted to provide a few details that I can't do in a comment.

I'm having the exact same issue with switching between views in a `UITabBarController` and when I come back to the first view, the `AdBannerView` is there, but doesn't actually show any ads for 1 minute, even though the delegate methods are being run.

I firstly went and followed this guide (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_0Mv44FWw0A&feature=youtu.be) on how to set up Shared instances of `AdBannerViews` which may or may not be what you're doing, but this could help; you never know.

In my case, that didn't do anything.

But I did implement `viewWillDisappear`:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.adBanner.delegate = nil;
    self.adBanner = nil;
    [self.adBanner removeFromSuperview];

}
```

If I comment out that code, I receive the same error you're facing in the console, with Error Code 7. If I don't comment out that code, I get through without any errors (i.e the `didFailToReceiveAdWithError` never gets run).

However, the issue I'm facing is that when I come back to the view from another tab, the viewWillAppear gets run, followed instantly by the `bannerViewDidLoadAd`, but that doesn't actually bring in the ad for 1 minute and instead I'm left with a blank white banner.

Also, I'm running the loading code from the `viewWillAppear` (because this gets called every time you come back to this `ViewController`, instead of `viewDidLoad`.

```
self.adBanner = [[self appdelegate] adBanner];
self.adBanner.delegate = self;
[self.adBanner setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 101, 320, 580)];    
[self.view addSubview:self.adBanner];
```

I'm not sure if this will help. I hope it does and if it does, perhaps we can work together to understand why mine doesn't work on iOS 8, either!